# Soften edges in javascript canvas image

Tags: javascript, image-processing, html5-canvas, image-manipulation

I am using [body-pix](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2019/11/updated-bodypix-2.html) to create a mask of a person from a webcam image and replacing the background in real time using straight ImageData byte manipulation on an HTM Canvas, replacing non mask pixels with pixels from a background image.

Although this works, the edges of the person mask are very sharp:

[image: Example]

I am able to manipulate the mask in isolation over a transparent background, so my idea was to soften the edges of the mask by making the pixels near the edge of the mask semi transparent, the closer to the edge the more transparent.

Is there an easy algorithm to do this by iterating over the bytes? I can find many examples of blurring/sharpening etc, but I really on want to consider the edges of the mask in this case.

Thanks.

Update: With advice from Blindman67 I have tried to use filters and compositing but the result is just a blurred background image.

```
maskWithBackgroundImage: async function(outputCanvas, videoStream, backgroundImageName, frameWidth, frameHeight) {
  service.FRAME_WIDTH = frameWidth;
  service.FRAME_HEIGHT = frameHeight;

  service.net = await bodyPix.load({
    architecture: service.filterProps.architecture,
    outputStride: service.filterProps.outputStride,
    multiplier: service.filterProps.multiplier,
    quantBytes: service.filterProps.quantBytes
  });

  service.videoCanvas = service.createCanvas();
  service.maskCanvas = document.getElementById('maskCanvas');
  service.videoCanvasContext = service.videoCanvas.getContext('2d');

  service.setupBackgroundImage(backgroundImageName).then(() => {
    service.segmentInRealTime(outputCanvas, videoStream);
  });
},
segmentInRealTime: async function(outputCanvas, videoStream) {
  let outputCanvasCtx = outputCanvas.getContext('2d');

  //Draw he latest video frame
  service.videoCanvasContext.drawImage(videoStream, 0, 0, service.FRAME_WIDTH, service.FRAME_HEIGHT);

  //STEP 1 - Draw BG image out
  outputCanvasCtx.drawImage(service.backgroundImage, 0, 0);

  //STEP 2 - Get black and transparent mask
  const personSegmentationImageData = await service.net.segmentPerson(service.videoCanvas, {
    internalResolution: 'medium',
    segmentationThreshold: service.filterProps.segmentationThreshold,
    maxDetections: service.filterProps.maxDetections
  });

  let maskData = service.replaceNonHumanWithTransparency(personSegmentationImageData);  //service.replaceNonHumanWithTransparency(personSegmentationImageData);
  let maskCanvasCtx = service.maskCanvas.getContext('2d');

  maskCanvasCtx.putImageData(maskData, 0, 0);

  let maskImg = new Image();

  maskImg.onload = function() {
    //STEP 3 - Set blur and composite
    outputCanvasCtx.filter = 'blur(1px)';
    outputCanvasCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
    outputCanvasCtx.drawImage(maskImg, 0, 0);
    outputCanvasCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
    outputCanvasCtx.drawImage(videoStream, 0, 0);
    outputCanvasCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';

    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      service.segmentInRealTime(outputCanvas, videoStream);
    });
  };
  maskImg.src = service.maskCanvas.toDataURL();
},
replaceNonHumanWithTransparency: function(
  personOrPartSegmentation, foreground = {
    r: 0,
    g: 0,
    b: 0,
    a: 0
  }, background = {
    r: 0,
    g: 0,
    b: 0,
    a: 255
  }, foregroundIds = [1]) {

  if (Array.isArray(personOrPartSegmentation) &&
    personOrPartSegmentation.length === 0) {
    return null;
  }

  let multiPersonOrPartSegmentation;

  if (!Array.isArray(personOrPartSegmentation)) {
    multiPersonOrPartSegmentation = [personOrPartSegmentation];
  } else {
    multiPersonOrPartSegmentation = personOrPartSegmentation;
  }

  const {width, height} = multiPersonOrPartSegmentation[0];

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  const bytes = new Uint8ClampedArray(width * height * 4);

  for (let i = 0; i < height; i += 1) {
    for (let j = 0; j < width; j += 1) {
      const n = i * width + j;

      bytes[4 * n + 0] = background.r; // background.r;
      bytes[4 * n + 1] = background.g; //background.g;
      bytes[4 * n + 2] = background.b; //background.b;
      bytes[4 * n + 3] = background.a; //background.a;
      for (let k = 0; k < multiPersonOrPartSegmentation.length; k++) {
        if (foregroundIds.some(
          id => id === multiPersonOrPartSegmentation[k].data[n])) {
          bytes[4 * n] = foreground.r;
          bytes[4 * n + 1] = foreground.g;
          bytes[4 * n + 2] = foreground.b;
          bytes[4 * n + 3] = foreground.a;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  return new ImageData(bytes, width, height);
}
```

With this result [image]

The mask is rendering fine and so is rendering the background image. Mixing the two together is causing me issues. Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: I doubt it's going to be possible to get much improvement over what you have already if you want something that works in real time. Blurring the alpha channel is just going to give you weird halo effects. Film studios use [chroma keying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key) for a good reason.

Comment: Thanks, the static image doesn't show how bad it looks. The edges look very sharp when you run in realtime and also has a really bad flicking effect around the edges. That's why I thought fading the edges might reduce that a lot.

Comment: Use a blur filter and composite the images Rather than draw the BG and FG using image data create a mask, eg all red pixels transparent the rest black. Draw the full BG image using `ctx,drawImage` then set the `ctx.filter` to blur 1px and `globalCompositeOperation` gCO to `"destination-out"`. Draw the mask (will cut out with blurred edge), turn off blur set gCO  = `"destination-over"` draw the full foreground image. Reset gCO to `"source-over"` Could be quicker than what you have as you only need to access the mask imgData (image with red pixels) rather than all 3 images

Comment: Thanks @Blindman67. Really appreciate that. I'm not sure if I've missed something, but I'm only getting a blurry background image from that. I've updated my question to include the code if you have time to have a quick look. Thanks.

Comment: Turn off  blur after drawing the mask. Add `ctx.filter = "none"` after the line `ctx.drawImage(maskImg, 0, 0);` Your code is very inefficient, Use `Uint32Array` rather than `Uint8ClampedArray` (over 4 times faster per pixel write). Dont recreate the  array each time, create it once and reuse it , and why on earth convert the mask to an image via a dataURL? You have the image already as `service.maskCanvas` After you add the pixels to it draw it using `ctx.drawImage(service.maskCanvas, 0, 0)`. And how large is `foregroundIds` as using `some` is so SLOWWWWW

Comment: @Blindman67 Thanks, got it working! Most of the code I got from body-pix examples (Google guys!) which uses Uint8ClampedArray and also the mask creation using 'some' is taken straight from their code. Anyways, will go and optimise now! Thank you very much for your help. The end result is a lot better than I did have. The dataUrl thing was me trying thing to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a  function similar to drawBokehEffect and replace the background used there with your own. drawBokehEffect uses the blurred video as background and on top of it - you. You have the function const personMask = createPersonMask(multiPersonSegmentation, edgeBlurAmount);
to create the mask with blurred edges (see https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/1db6ba191bec70d8953bd3c6e274213dbbbbd778/body-pix/src/output_rendering_util.ts#L505 )

so the steps in this function are very simple:

1.create the personMask

2.clearRect canvas

3.drawImage (video, 0 0 width height) on canvas

4.drawWithCompositing(canvas, personMask, 'destination-in');

5.drawWithCompositing(canvas, backgroundOfChoice, 'destination-over');

6.restore(); canvas

tested and works